# Textarea not working with jQuery live keyup function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

I'm trying to build a tag friend system for a personal project. I've found some great tutorials online but right now i'm stuck.

Nothing happens when i type in @ in the tagbox. Display and msgbox should slide down so users can select a friend they want to tag.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<div id="tagbox">
    <div class="textarea">
        <textarea id="contentbox" name="contentbox"></textarea>
        <div id='display'></div>
        <div id="msgbox"></div>
        <button type="submit" id="tag_button" value="Update" name="submit">Add</button>
    </div>
```

And here's the AJAX/jQuery part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var start=/@/ig;
        var word=/@(\w+)/ig;

        $('#tagbox .textarea textarea[name="contentbox"]').live("keyup",function() {
            var content=$(this).text();
            var go= content.match(start);
            var name= content.match(word);
            var dataString = 'searchword='+ name;

            if(go.length>0) {
                $("#msgbox").slideDown('show');
                $("#display").slideUp('show');
                $("#msgbox").html("Type the name of someone or something...");
                if(name.length>0) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "addfriends.php",
                        data: dataString,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(html) {
                            $("#msgbox").hide();
                            $("#display").html(html).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            return false();
        });

        $(".addname").live("click",function() {
            var username=$(this).attr('title');
            var old=$('#tagbox .textarea textarea[name="contentbox"]').html();
            var content=old.replace(word,""); 
            $('#ws3 .textarea textarea[name="contentbox"]').html(content);
            var E="<a class='red' contenteditable='false' href='#' >"+username+"</a>";
            $('#tagbox').append(E);
            $("#display").hide();
            $("#msgbox").hide();
            $('#ws3').focus();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `.live` is deprecated. You should use `.on` or `.delegate`.

Comment: Why not `$('#contentbox')` instead of  `$('#tagbox .textarea textarea[name="contentbox"]')` .. `ID` is supposed to be unique on a page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the value of `textarea` you must use the method `.val()` instead of `text()` otherwise `content` will always be empty.

```
var content=$(this).val();
```

Comment: omg that was driving me crazy! I couldn't understand why a keyup on the textarea always showed the original value.. I was using jQuery(this).text() instead of jQuery(this).val()